# 2 pole outlet & 2 pole breakers

Tags: lighting

In USA AC system, A 2 pole circuit breaker means both hot lines (120v) are connected to the breakers. How about a 2 pole outlet. Does it also mean both hot pair of 120v are connected to the 2 pole outlet?  Or does 2 pole mean other thing when in comes to outlet? Any illustration would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that each hot in a 240 V receptacle goes to one, and only one, of the linked breakers of the 2-pole breaker that serves the circuit.

**EDIT**

I am answering here while admitting that my knowledge is limited.

The average US household will have two different types of 240 V circuit--three wire and four wire as follows:

1. Three wire: hot1-hot2-ground. This gives 240 V between the two hots and services loads at 240 V only, e.g. an electric hot water heater.
2. Three wire: hot1-hot2-neutral. This is no longer allowed in new construction but is grandfathered. The receptacle for this will serve loads at both 120 V and 240 V. Our electric clothes dryer is served by this type from a 30-A 2-pole breaker.
3. Four wire: hot1-hot2-neutral-ground. This will serve loads which require both 120 V (one hot to neutral) and 240 V (hot to hot).

In the usual US residence each 240 V circuit is dedicated to one outlet. For example, our electric range is served by one 50-A 2-pole breaker which serves only the receptacle for the range.

A continuous conductor goes from one side of the 2-pole breaker to one of the hot slots in the receptacle, and another continuous conductor goes from the other side of the same 2-pole breaker to the other hot slot in the receptacle . (The receptacle also has slots for neutral and ground, and separate conductors connect them, respectively,  to the neutral and ground bars in the panel.)

Comment: But are the two hot lines connected to the same receptacle?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: In the Philippines. We only have 1 configuration which you described "A continuous conductor goes from one side of the 2-pole breaker to one of the hot slots in the receptacle, and another continuous conductor goes from the other side of the same 2-pole breaker to the other hot slot in the receptacle". However I found out that 2-pole didn't mean the same thing in a receptable. A 2-pole receptacle is simply one where both the line & neutral have separate switch. A 1-pole receptacle means only the line has switch. So 2-pole in receptacle doesn't mean the same thing as 2-pole in circuit breaker.

Comment: In the Philippines are all receptacles switched? Or all high current receptacles switched? In the US receptacles are usually not switched (except of course at the breakers). Our kitchen range and dryer receptacles are not switched. The one exception at our house is the air conditioning condensing unit. The circuit is hot1-hot2-ground, I believe. There is a 2-pole switch in a box on the side of the house next to the a/c condensing unit. Each of the two hots is switched.

Comment: No. None are switched. Not even air conditioning condensing unit. We only use switch for light. I was initially asking about 2-pole receptacle hoping that the 2-pole gfci outlets at amazon were 2 hot lines giving 240v. But they were not. My hope is to get European RCD with automatic self-test. If none of them has this feature, then only choice are those 2 pole gfci breakers. But these seem to need neutral for the electronic board to function correctly by it tapping the 120v. Next I have to figure out is if the ground outside service entrance are connected to the centertap of transformer or not

Comment: The only correction I would make is 240v circuits can have more than 1 outlet, many times they do have just 1 but this is not required by code. As Jim suggests on AC units a local disconnect is required within site of the unit. Pole on a switch is how many conductors can be switched 1 pole = 1, 2 pole=2 . The throws are how many different connections the pole can make